# APIC 2018.3.7 OVA: The Assembly part of API is not being deployed - has reverted to a much earlier version?

Tags: ibm-datapower, apiconnect, apic

As of yesterday, when I publish the (current) Product and its API, the deployed Assembly is not updated and what is running is from an earlier state - most likely from early December. The APIC domain was created at the end of Nov, so what I is deployed could even be the initial deployment.

As a test, I changed the API's description (add 'XXX') and changed a Gateway script to add XXX to a 'console.warn' at the start of the Assembly. The description change can be seen in Portal, but there is no 'XXX' visible in the DP log. I set DP log level to 'debug', but none of the 'tracing' statements added in Dec can be seen.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can resolve this? Or, how can I see the API's deployed code? I've looked in the DP File Management, but everything is dated at then end of Nov.

[EDIT]

Catalogs are in Dev mode, so I change and publish using same version. I have just done a series of tests using the api referred to above (VAT-Num-Check) (which is our first 'real' api) and an older trivial one that just divides two numbers. The Sandbox catalog is associated with the DEV gateway, and the SIT catalog, with the SIT gateway.

The other kind of corruption is, after deploying a new api, calling it results in 404 'No resources match requested URI'.

My conclusions are:

Something has broken in Mgmt server and/or DP APiC Gateway. Once code has been deployed to DP, it can't be changed or deleted. Changes in Portal are correct.

The possible exception is that the deployment of the VAT-Num-check API appears to have reverted to an earlier version after a CLI publish to the SIT Gateway this morning.

[/EDIT]

Background:

I have been creating a Windows script to publish draft Product/APIs and then run Postman tests. This means that I have been performing a lot of publish actions to DP (V5 type).  On Monday evening, in my last run, the Postman tests all worked. Yesterday morning, some failed.

Back in early Dec, I made a change so that all JSON error messages in user responses used *error* as the 'prefix' to the message contents. Before that, some used *message* and some used *reply*. The reason for the failures is error messages have reverted to using the earlier 'prefix'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API Connect 2018.3.7 went out of support on November 15, 2018. You'd need to upgrade to 2018.4.1.x, which will be supported for a longer term.

If you still have the issue at that point, then please open a support ticket for further investigation.

Comment: I am waiting for my customer's Tech Group to schedule install 4.1.1. 
I was hoping someone might have come across this and have a suggestion for now. I'm going to import swagger code to a clean installation of 4.1.1. If the issue is due to a significant number of publishes to DP, then it might show up eventually.
I understand the support position - thanks for clarifying.